# How to interpret output of body-segmentation (ImageData)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, bodypix

I am looking to better understand how the output of how body-segmentation works https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-segmentation. I have the code working and am seeing an ImageData. How would I use this to know where specific body parts are being detected in the image? I thought these would be labeled in a simpler array. I was able to use some of the utility functions, but I was hoping to better understand how they are reading the mask to highlight certain body parts. Thank you.
[image]